# No bean of type [io.micronaut.data.mongodb.operations.MongoRepositoryOperations] exists

Tags: java, mongodb, micronaut

No bean of type [io.micronaut.data.mongodb.operations.MongoRepositoryOperations] exists. Make sure the bean is not disabled by bean requirements (enable trace logging for 'io.micronaut.context.condition' to check) and if the bean is enabled then ensure the class is declared a bean and annotation processing is enabled (for Java and Kotlin the 'micronaut-inject-java' dependency should be configured as an annotation processor).
I'm using MongoDB as a database raised in docker as a container here are my codes with pom xml and docker compose

I already tried to put some dependencies but I couldn't run it, it will always give this error when I make a request in postman

`Entity`

```
package br.com.entity;

import io.micronaut.core.annotation.Creator;
import io.micronaut.core.annotation.Introspected;
import io.micronaut.data.annotation.GeneratedValue;
import io.micronaut.data.annotation.Id;
import io.micronaut.data.annotation.MappedEntity;
import io.micronaut.serde.annotation.Serdeable;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotEmpty;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import org.bson.types.ObjectId;


@Introspected
@MappedEntity("Person")
@Serdeable
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(GeneratedValue.Type.IDENTITY)
    private ObjectId id;
    @NotNull
    @NotBlank
    private String name;
    @NotNull
    @NotBlank
    private int age;
    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    private String gender;

    @Creator
    public Person(@NotNull String name,
                  @NotNull int age,
                  @NotEmpty String gender) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.gender = gender;
    }
    public Person(){
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public ObjectId getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(ObjectId id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
    public String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }
    public void setGender(String gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }
}
```

`Repository`

```
package br.com.repository;

import br.com.entity.Person;
import io.micronaut.data.mongodb.annotation.MongoRepository;
import io.micronaut.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.bson.types.ObjectId;



@MongoRepository
public interface PersonRepository extends CrudRepository<Person, ObjectId> {
}
```

`Service`

```
package br.com.service;

import br.com.Person;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotEmpty;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import org.bson.types.ObjectId;

import java.util.Optional;


public interface PersonService {

    Optional<Person> findById(@NotNull ObjectId id);

    Person save(@NotNull Person person);

    void deleteById(ObjectId id);

    Iterable<Person>  findAll();

    Person update(@NotNull ObjectId id, @NotEmpty Person updatedPerson);
}
```

`Service implent`

```
package br.com.service;

import br.com.entity.Person;
import br.com.repository.PersonRepository;
import io.micronaut.core.annotation.NonNull;
import io.micronaut.data.exceptions.EmptyResultException;
import jakarta.inject.Inject;
import jakarta.inject.Singleton;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotEmpty;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import org.bson.types.ObjectId;
import java.util.Optional;



@Singleton
public class PersonServiceImpl implements PersonService {

    @Inject
    private PersonRepository personRepository;

    public PersonServiceImpl(PersonRepository personRepository) {
        this.personRepository = personRepository;
    }

    public Optional<Person> findById(@NonNull ObjectId personId) {
        return personRepository.findById(personId);
    }

    public Person save(Person person) {
        return personRepository.save(person);
    }


    public void deleteById(ObjectId personId) {
        personRepository.deleteById(personId);
    }

    public Iterable<Person> findAll() {
        return personRepository.findAll();
    }

    public Person update(@NotNull ObjectId id, @NotEmpty Person updatedPerson) {

        Optional<Person> optionalPerson = findById(id);

        if (optionalPerson.isPresent()) {

            Person existingPerson = optionalPerson.get();

            existingPerson.setName(updatedPerson.getName());
            existingPerson.setAge(updatedPerson.getAge());
            existingPerson.setGender(updatedPerson.getGender());
            return personRepository.update(existingPerson);
        } else {
            throw new EmptyResultException();
        }
    }
}
```

`Controller`

```
package br.com.controller;

import br.com.entity.Person;
import br.com.service.PersonServiceImpl;
import io.micronaut.http.HttpResponse;
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.*;
import jakarta.validation.Valid;
import org.bson.types.ObjectId;
import java.util.Optional;


@Controller("/api/person")
public class PersonController {

    private PersonServiceImpl personService;

    public PersonController(PersonServiceImpl personService) {
        this.personService = personService;
    }

    @Get("/{personId}")
    public HttpResponse<Person> findById(@PathVariable @Valid ObjectId personId) {
        Optional<Person> person = personService.findById(personId);
        return person.map(HttpResponse::ok).orElseGet(HttpResponse::notFound);
    }

    @Post
    public HttpResponse<Person> save(@Body Person person) {
        Person savedPerson = personService.save(person);
        return HttpResponse.created(savedPerson);
    }

    @Delete("/{personId}")
    public HttpResponse<?> deleteById(@PathVariable ObjectId personId) {
        personService.deleteById(personId);
        return HttpResponse.noContent();
    }

    @Get
    public HttpResponse<Iterable<Person>> findAll() {
        Iterable<Person> persons = personService.findAll();
        return HttpResponse.ok(persons);
    }

    @Put("/{id}")
    public HttpResponse<Person> update(@PathVariable ObjectId id, @Body @Valid Person updatedPerson) {
        Person updated = personService.update(id, updatedPerson);
        return HttpResponse.ok(updated);
    }
}
```

```
micronaut:
  application:
    name: AtividadeCrud
    logging:
      level:
        io.micronaut.context.condition: TRACE

datasources:
  default:
    url: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?directConnection=true&serverSelectionTimeoutMS=2000&appName=mongosh+1.10.1
    database: atividadeDB
    driver-class-name: io.micronaut.configuration.mongo.sync.MongoSyncDriver

mongodb:
  uri: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?directConnection=true&serverSelectionTimeoutMS=2000&appName=mongosh+1.10.1
  databases:
    mongodb-uri: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?directConnection=true&serverSelectionTimeoutMS=2000&appName=mongosh+1.10.1
    database: atividadeDB
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>br.com</groupId>
  <artifactId>AtividadeCrud</artifactId>
  <version>0.1</version>
  <packaging>${packaging}</packaging>

  <parent>
    <groupId>io.micronaut.platform</groupId>
    <artifactId>micronaut-parent</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0</version>
  </parent>
  <properties>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <jdk.version>17</jdk.version>
    <release.version>17</release.version>
    <micronaut.version>4.0.0</micronaut.version>
    <micronaut.aot.enabled>false</micronaut.aot.enabled>
    <micronaut.aot.packageName>br.com.aot.generated</micronaut.aot.packageName>
    <micronaut.data.version>4.0.1</micronaut.data.version>
    <micronaut.runtime>netty</micronaut.runtime>
    <exec.mainClass>br.com.Application</exec.mainClass>
  </properties>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>sonatype-snapshots</id>
      <url>https://s01.oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <releases>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </releases>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <id>central</id>
      <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-http-server-netty</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut.data</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-data-mongodb</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut.mongodb</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-mongo-sync</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut.serde</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-serde-jackson</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut.validation</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-validation</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.validation</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.validation-api</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
      <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
      <artifactId>mongodb-driver-sync</artifactId>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-http-client</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut.test</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-test-junit5</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
      <artifactId>mongodb</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
      <artifactId>testcontainers</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
      <artifactId>mongodb-driver-reactivestreams</artifactId>
      <version>4.10.2</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>io.micronaut.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>micronaut-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <configuration>
            <configFile>aot-${packaging}.properties</configFile>
          </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <!-- Uncomment to enable incremental compilation -->
          <!-- <useIncrementalCompilation>false</useIncrementalCompilation> -->

          <annotationProcessorPaths combine.self="override">


            <path>
              <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
              <artifactId>micronaut-inject-java</artifactId>
              <version>${micronaut.core.version}</version>
            </path>
            <path>
              <groupId>io.micronaut.data</groupId>
              <artifactId>micronaut-data-processor</artifactId>
              <version>${micronaut.data.version}</version>
              <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                  <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
                  <artifactId>micronaut-inject</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
              </exclusions>
            </path>
            <path>
              <groupId>io.micronaut.data</groupId>
              <artifactId>micronaut-data-document-processor</artifactId>
              <version>${micronaut.data.version}</version>
              <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                  <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
                  <artifactId>micronaut-inject</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
              </exclusions>
            </path>
            <path>
              <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
              <artifactId>micronaut-graal</artifactId>
              <version>${micronaut.core.version}</version>
            </path>
            <path>
              <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
              <artifactId>micronaut-http-validation</artifactId>
              <version>${micronaut.version}</version>
            </path>
            <path>
              <groupId>io.micronaut.serde</groupId>
              <artifactId>micronaut-serde-processor</artifactId>
              <version>${micronaut.serialization.version}</version>
              <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                  <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
                  <artifactId>micronaut-inject</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
              </exclusions>
            </path>
            <path>
              <groupId>io.micronaut.validation</groupId>
              <artifactId>micronaut-validation-processor</artifactId>
              <version>${micronaut.validation.version}</version>
              <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                  <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
                  <artifactId>micronaut-inject</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
              </exclusions>
            </path>
          </annotationProcessorPaths>
          <compilerArgs>
            <arg>-Amicronaut.processing.group=br.com.phoebus</arg>
            <arg>-Amicronaut.processing.module=AtividadeCrud</arg>
          </compilerArgs>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Edit you code please, also the answer is there is no bean of MongoRepositoryOperation in you IOC coctainner.

Comment: Also see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70113424/application-wont-start-as-mongooperations-bean-is-not-defined please.